# preg_replace Regular Expression not match

Tags: php, regex

i have a string like

```
abcd : 12
<br />
cc : 25
<br />
some : 0
<br />
make : 02.36
<br />
Kk : 11.00
<br />
mm : 0
```

i want to remove all line who have `: 0`

i try

```
$ragid  = "|<br />s*(.*?) : 0 s*(.*?)<br />|i"; 
$text=preg_replace($ragid,"",$text);
```

but it replace all string start from `<br />` and end to `<br />`

it not match the perfect as i want. 
any solution for that ?

Comment: What is the expected output, sir Toms?

Comment: That regex doesn't match any part of your text example. Are you sure you've copied/pasted it correctly here (I suspect you want `\s*` where you're having `s*`)?

Comment: i want to remove all line which have `:0` NiftyDude, no i want only remove line having `: 0` not having `: 02.36`

Comment: You **really** shouldn't use `|` as your regex delimiter. It prevents you from using `|` as the *OR* operator in your regexps.

Comment: Does that mean you also want to remove the line `make : 02.36`?

Comment: What does qualify as a line? A line as in regex or a line as in the browser?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
preg_replace('/(^|<br\s*\/?>)\s*(.*?)\s*:\s*0(\s+|$)/i', '', $str);
```

**EDIT**
And [here is the output](http://pastie.org/private/mp4xrqcixtj06qrpmxtmtg) after doing a quick test.

Comment: Now that I think about it, the `i` makes sense in case someone is angrily typing <BR /> WITH ALL CAPS, so I've added it back in.

Answer (score 1):

Per line is easy if you use the multi-line mode of PCRE (`m`-modifier):

```
~^.*$~m
```

This will make `^` match the beginning of a line and `$` the end of a line.

So to match all lines that contain `: 0` at their end:

```
~^(.*: 0$\n?)~m
```

If you need more compatibility for line endings, you can use `\R` instead of `\n` to make the line-ending configureable. The option `(*ANYCRLF)` is also hinting what `^` and `$` means:

```
~(*ANYCRLF)^(.*: 0$\R?)~m
```

Example:

```
$str = <<<STR
abcd : 12
<br />
cc : 25
<br />
some : 0
<br />
make : 02.36
<br />
Kk : 11.00
<br />
mm : 0
STR;

echo preg_replace('~(*ANYCRLF)^(.*: 0$\R?)~m', '', $str);
```

Output:

```
abcd : 12
<br />
cc : 25
<br />
<br />
make : 02.36
<br />
Kk : 11.00
<br />
```

Comment: no no no, don't replace `make : 02.36` only replace `: 0` line

Comment: @Toms: `~^(.*: 0$\R?)~m` -that's `: 0` at the end.

Comment: `preg_replace('~^(.*: 0$\R?)~m', '', $str);` this is not worked

Comment: @Toms: Edited the answer, if you use the `\R` variant and non-UNIX line-endings, you should also specify what `\R` and `$` resp. `^` means. That actually should make it work cross-platform, see [Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rIzYP2).

Answer (score 0):

I think the expression you are looking for ist something like that: `/.* : 0\n/i`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$text = preg_replace('~<br />\s[^:]* : 0\s?~', '', $text);
```

Comment: Close but that last `\s` won't match input that ends in `0` with no newline thereafter.

Comment: @inspectorg: I just noticed that and fixed it, however I also spotted another problem with mine (yours too): if the first line is `x : 0` it won't get removed.

Comment: your output like this 
`abcd : 12 
cc : 25 2.36 
Kk : 11.00` where `make` string goes ?

Comment: @Toms: Indeed, there are other problems too, you should accept inspectorg answer.